# multiple php installations

Tags: php

I am looking to see what it takes to have multiple installs of php in osx 10.5.
I found this  [page](http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/) that goes on to explain it for windows.

I was looking for confirmation from someone that knows better than me, if the steps are very similar for 10.5.

I am a novice user. Having only scripted with php, not actually building or installing it.
My web host runs a php older than I have installed. And I'd like to at least test locally on a version the same as my remote option.

Any  help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is one of the servers running PHP 5 and the other PHP 4?

If so you can run PHP 5 in PHP 4 mode by enabling the following in your php.ini file:

`zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = 1`

If you can't edit the php.ini file then you can't change the local version for the script running by adding the following to your PHP script:

`@ini_set('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode', 1);`

Comment: I'd upvote this, but can't, not enough points or something. This is the simplest solution to what I need 2 installs for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should find a tutorial for Linux or BSD, which would be a lot more helpful then a Windows-based one.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I managed to do it on WIndows and wrote a quick [how-to](http://forums.dathorn.com/showthread.php?t=2884). While I don't believe it could be much relevant to OS X (except maybe for the part showing how to switch engine in `.htaccess`) I can give you some hint about the basic points:

1. Install as CGI, not as an Apache module;
2. ignore any instruction to put your `php.in`i in a common location or set up environment variables pointing to a single `php.ini`: what you definitely need is a separate php.ini for each PHP version, so you have to put them in the respective PHP folder to be found;
3. when testing check with `phpinfo()` which `php.ini` is actually being loaded.

Just for sake of completeness I'd add that at the time of writing (2007) both PHP4 and PHP5 were happy to run with each other's `php.ini` - until I started loading extensions: those are compiled for their PHP version only and go into a spin if used with the wrong PHP.

Hope I've been helpful.